# Is a ring with the following properties semiprime? (Part 2)

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with $1 \neq 0$ that contains noncentral idempotents.  If for every noncentral idempotent $e$ of $R$ the corner ring $eRe$ is a division ring and $eR(1-e)Re \neq 0$, is the ring $R$ semiprime?

Comment: You should try merging your accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify my [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90377/274) by modding out by all paths of length $3$ you get a counterexample.

Comment: Is there a way to describe this modified example in terms of matrices?

Comment: Sure. But there is a reason why people love quivers.... :D

Comment: Fair enough, but for right now, I understand matrices much better.  If you can help with this, I'd really appreciate it.  Either way thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: If you like examples (and you should) you simply *must* become familiar with quivers and relations.

Comment: Could you recommend a good introduction to quivers?

Comment: The first volume of the book by Assem, Skowroński and Simson on representation theory. The first couple of chapters, in fact.